# alignment issues when showing the subtext for a label - html

Tags: html, css

I have the below html code,i want to add a subtext(select Dates) for MyCalendar label.

```html
<tr style="height:5%;">
  <td colspan="2">
    <span style="float:right;"> <label style="float: right">MyCalendar<input id="t1" class="sid myClassValue" style="float: right" ng-model="myData"></label> </span>
    <span style="float:left;"> <a style="text-align: right; float: right; color: #c94e00" target="_blank" href="http://myURL.com">Click on link</a> </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I tried as below but the alignment is not as expected:

```html
<tr style="height:5%;">
  <td colspan="2">
    <span style="float:right;"> <label style="float: right;display:block;">MyCalendar: <br /><span> <font size="1">(select Dates) <font size="1"></span><input id="t1" class="sid myClassValue" style="float: right" ng-model="myData"></label>
    </span>
    <span style="float:left;"> <a style="text-align: right; float: right; color: #c94e00" target="_blank" href="http://myURL.com">Click on link</a> </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How do you want it to look like?

Comment: down to MyCalendar label as a subtext for MyCalendar.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using **:after** element like this so you don't have to touch your HTML structure :

```css
span.more label {
    position: relative;
}
span.more label:after {
    content: "(Select dates)";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<tr style="height:5%;">
  <td colspan="2">
    <span class="more" style="float:right;"> <label style="float: right">MyCalendar<input id="t1" class="sid myClassValue" style="float: right" ng-model="myData"></label> </span>
    <span style="float:left;"> <a style="text-align: right; float: right; color: #c94e00" target="_blank" href="http://myURL.com">Click on link</a> </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```